# Recursive Stock Maximization

Tags: algorithm, recursion, memoization

The problem is to maximize the profit of a stock given the prices of stock on a given day.
I can buy only 1 stock, sell any number or do nothing.

```
Test cases:
Input: 1 2 100
Output: 197
Explanation: Bought on day 1 and day 2 sold on day 3 total profit = (100 - 1) + (100 - 2) = 197

Input: 1 3 1 2
Output: 3
Explanation: buy one share on day 1, sell one on day 2, buy one share on day 3, and sell one share on day 4.
```

I have a recursive solution below and I know there are other solutions but I am trying to build on from a recursive one:

```
int maxProfit(vector<int> stock)
{
    int profit = helper(stock, stock[0], 1, 1);
    return profit < 0 ? 0 : profit;
}

int helper(vector<int>& stock, int cost, int index, int stockcount)
{
    if (index == stock.size() - 1)
    {
        return (stock[index] * stockcount) - cost;
    }
    int buy = helper(stock, cost + stock[index], index + 1, stockcount + 1);
    int sell = helper(stock, cost - stock[index], index + 1, stockcount - 1);
    return max(buy, sell);
}
```

Is the algorithm a correct recurisve approach and is there a way I can memoize the above? possibly removing the accumulator `cost`?

Comment: I added code to my answer, demonstrating both the memoized recursion and the reverse traversal.

Answer (score 1):

The recursive solution you offer seems to account for the choice to buy one stock but ignore the choice to do nothing and the varied choice of selling any number of owned stock.

But most importantly, it ignores what in real life would be the most important advantage: knowing the future :)

If you were to traverse the array from the end to the beginning, keeping track of the highest price so far, think about what you would do if:

(1) the price you encounter is lower than the one in your record? (remember that your record is of a *future* price)

and (2) the price you encounter is the same or higher than the price in your record? (again, remember that the price in your record is the highest future price coming after the current viewed price)

(Regarding memoization - in general, one can memoize the return value of a function by hashing or creating a lookup table for its set of parameters, optimising by considering which of the parameters may be constant or could be made constant and therefore ignored. Memoization is useful if you expect the same set of parameters to be called many times repeatedly during the calculation.)

Below are a JavaScript version with memoization of the rules you described, followed by the `O(n)` reverse traversal I hinted at above.

Memoized recursion:

```js
function maxProfit(stock){
  return helper(stock, 0, 0, 0);
}

var hash = {};

function helper(stock, cost, index, stockcount){
  let key = [cost, index, stockcount].join('-');
  
  if (hash[key] !== undefined)
    return hash[key];

  if (index == stock.length)
    return -cost;

  var buy_or_not = helper(stock, cost + stock[index], index + 1, stockcount + 1);

  for (let i=0; i<=stockcount; i++)
    buy_or_not = Math.max(
      buy_or_not,
      helper(stock, cost - i*stock[index], index + 1, stockcount - i)
    );
      
  return hash[key] = buy_or_not;
}

console.log(maxProfit([1,1,50,1,1,50,1,1,40]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

`O(n)` reverse traversal:

```js
function f(arr){
  if (!arr.length)
    return 0;
    
  var i = arr.length - 1,
      highest_sale_price = arr[i],
      stock_count = 0,
      current_cost = 0,
      total_profit = 0;
      
  for (i--; i>=0; i--){
    // Wouldn't want to buy this
    if (arr[i] >= highest_sale_price){
      
    // Go back to the future and
    // sell anything bought after
    // this day at the next highest
    // price
    total_profit += stock_count * highest_sale_price - current_cost;
    
    highest_sale_price = arr[i];
    current_cost = 0;
    stock_count = 0;

    // Otherwise, we know a 
    // higher future price
    // so buy this stock!
    } else {
      stock_count++;
      current_cost += arr[i];
    }
  }

  // Day 0, go back to the future and sell
  // anything we have left at a higher price
  if (highest_sale_price)
    total_profit += stock_count * highest_sale_price - current_cost;

  return total_profit;
}

console.log(f([1,1,50,1,1,50,1,1,40]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: The varied or the number of stocks sold is accounted for in the `stockcount`. To make the recursion do nothing I could add another branch to just do `int donothing = helper(stock, cost, index + 1, stockcount)` - I could go with what you suggest but then it beats the purpose of having to solve this recursively.

Comment: @SamerTufail Ah, I see the stock count. But the choices of selling different numbers of stocks does not seem to be elaborated.

Comment: In the question you mean? `sell any number` if its not clear I can edit it.

Comment: @SamerTufail no, in your answer :) The recursion you posted only branches with a sale of one stock (stockcount - 1), but you said there's a choice to sell between zero and all of the currently owned stock at each iteration.

Comment: Agreed, however it does account for all the stocks sold in the base case where it eventually uses the stock count to make the sale. I had it different in a previous version where the argument passed in the selling was equal to `(stock[index] * stockcount) - cost`. I called that `profit` but to simplify memoization I got rid of that variable and coded it as above.

Comment: @SamerTufail Does your program succeed for `stock = [1,1,50,1,1,50,1,1,40]`?

Comment: for that test case I get: 254, what is the expected output?

Comment: @SamerTufail What do you think is the expected output? (Hint: (buy,buy,sell) x 3)

Answer (score 1):

**Terminology**: a *stock* is a particular ownership class of a company, such as INTC for Intel or MSFT for Microsoft common stock.  The individual partitions you buy and sell are called *shares*.

As גלעד ברקן already pointed out, *you know the future*.  There is no guessing, no dollar-averaging, no partial solutions.  You have total information.

**Lemma**: If it makes sense to sell 1 share of stock it makes sense to sell all you have.  This will greatly simplify your algorithm: you don't have to explore the alternative from 1-**N**.

**Lemma**: If today's price is lower than the future max price, the best strategy is to buy the maximum allowed.

**Algorithm**

```
// Base case:
If the array is empty, return

// Process
Find the maximum price in the array (call that day_s)
Buy max shares (one) on each day 1 : day_s
Sell all shares on day_s
(balance accounting is left as an exercise for the student)

// Recur
helper(stock[day_s: ], balance, 0)
```

Comment: The //recur at each step im finding the max in the array or is that a precomputation?

Comment: @SamerTufail that precomputation would be akin to the `O(n)` reverse traversal suggested in my answer. In this sense the recursion in this answer seems to just be a loop, there are no choice points (branches).

Comment: @SamerTufail: "Recur" is merely a label.

Comment: @גלעדברקן    That's correct: as with many recursive routines, there are no choice points.  This would be easily converted to a loop.

Comment: @Prune: I understood it was a label just that the label meant something which was the initiation of recursion. I think it would be hard to solve this problem by branching or an exhaustive approach, which was my intention.

Comment: It's not that hard to solve, just long-running.  You can continue as you started, doing the exhaustive search.  There are many examples of this technique, both on Stack Overflow and elsewhere on line.  You can look at the coin-change problem, for instance, to see a canonical example of this multiple-recursion style.

Comment: Memoization is a matter of indexing the solution via the machine state.  In this case, the state is the remaining prices and the quantity of shares you hold.  You can look up particular techniques for your preferred implementation language.  Python, for one, has a "memoized" decorator that does the work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the recursive solution. In this solution, I am checking for every value `i`, to see if I find a value of `j` such that `a[j] > a[i]`. Then I calculate the profit as `a[j] - a[i]` and then add the profit to the recurrence from index `j + 1` to `e`.

```
 int solve(int *a, int s, int e, int k){
    // passing array a, starting index s, ending index e, max stocks one 
    // can sell k

    // base case
    if(s>=e)return 0;
    if(k == 0)return 0;

    int ans = 0;

    for(int i = s; i<e; i++){        
      for(int j = i+1; j<=e; j++){
        int temp =0;
        if(a[j]>a[i]){
          temp += a[j] - a[i] + solve(a,j+1,e,k-1); 
        }
        ans = max(ans,temp);
      }             
    }
    return ans;
  }
```